# Sort an array in a specific order - not ascending/descending

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I'm working on an algorithm that works best if the inputs are passed to it in a particular order, so I want to sort them that way. The difference is drastic enough for me to consider re-sorting the array.

Consider an array `a` with length `n`. I want to sort it the following way, and return the array of indices of `a` instead of the values:

I define another array `w`, also of length `n`. I want to sort such that the first element is closest to the first element of `w`. Then, from the rest of the elements (excluding the one already sorted), the second element is closest to the second element of `w`, and so on.

For example `a = {5.5, 6.5, 2.4, 3.1}`, `w = {1, 2, 6, 5}`.

`2.4` is closest to `1`, so `output[0] = 2`, the index of `2.4`.

`2.4` is closest to `2`, but already processed, so choose `3.1`, `output[1] = 3`.

Next come `0` and `1`, in that order. `0` is chosen because it comes first, although both are equidistant.

So, `output = {2, 3, 0, 1}` and the sorted array would be `sorted = {2.4, 3.1, 5.5, 6.5}` (each index is used to find the corresponding element).

I can only think of brute-forcing this algorithm. Can there be a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: The 3rd paragraph is hard to understand. Could you improve it to make it more clear ?

Comment: Most library `Sort()` functions that I'm aware of let you provide your own `Compare(a,b)` function.  That would let you sort (for example) a list of strings by length instead of alphabet.

Comment: What are you going to do if multiple elements are equally "close" to one of your reference elements?  What if one element is equally close to two different reference elements?

Comment: @DanPichelman Compare only lets you do comparisons within the same array.

@TMN Pick any one, doesn't really matter in my case.

@user61852 I mean we exclude the first `i` elements of `w` on the `i`th iteration, but only the already sorted elements of `a` are excluded.

Comment: Can you add some short examples of what arrays `a` and `w` might look like before and after processing?

Comment: @DanPichelman I added those as per your request.

Comment: This looks more like matching than sorting

Comment: @HameerAbbasi - since both arrays are the same length and only use each term once, then what would make your intended code better than just sorting `a` & `w` independently.

Comment: @JamesSnell: His algorithm will make the first elements be closer.  E.g., his algorithm would yield `(5,5),(10,2),(15,1)` whereas yours would yield `(5,1),(10,2),(15,5)`. The total difference is the same either way, but his algorithm tends to have low distance results early on.

Comment: @Brian - thanks, I understood what his code was intended to do just not seeing what they're gaining through what is quite a complicated search/matching system to get to it.  Perhaps if there was a bit more information on what they're trying to actually solve maybe that might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Insert all elements of `a` into a [(self-balancing) Binary Search Tree (BST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) - O(n log n)
- For each element of `w`, lookup and remove the closest element in the BST and add it to the output - O(n log n)

  Finding the closest element in a BST is rather easy. If the element is greater than the current node's element, look right, if it's smaller, look left, if it's equal, stop. As you go down the tree, simply keep track of the closest element.

Having it return the indices instead of the element should be trivial.

Total running time - O(n log n)

Comment: +1: Better than my answer.

Comment: That'll work.  The key is that the current tree node defines one endpoint of a fully-closed interval, and either the left or right child defines the other endpoint of the interval.  The closest value will be found somewhere in that interval.  Actually, it will either be the current node, the child, or somewhere in subtree "between" the node and child.  (I.e., in the subsequence between the node value and the child node value, in an inorder traverse.)

Comment: +1 I don't think any kind of sorting algorithm has been made better than O(n log n). You just reduced my problem to that. Kudos! Marked yours as the answer for being the simplest here.

Comment: Marked as answer again for being closer to the exact algorithm. I didn't consider a self-balancing BST, or a `Balance()` function at all.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?  Sort both arrays numerically, remembering the original indexes for w so you can restore it quickly.  Then use w's unsort on a.  This would give you a result of {2, 3, 1, 0} rather than {2, 3, 0, 1}, but that *might* be a better answer, depending how you look at it, and it would be a bit faster than brute forcing it.

Comment: This is what I thought of too, and I think it might even be faster than Dukeling's :)

Comment: @sparkleshy: definitely faster. The real questions are the fine points in how __a__ aligns with __w__. Our solution provides a better overall alignment, the other aligns the first elements in __a__ perfectly and fits the last ones in however it can.

Comment: Both would be the same order since we're sorting numerically, first.

Comment: @RalphChapin Forgive my ignorance, but can you explain or link to what you mean by "use w's unsort on a"?

Comment: @HameerAbbasi: If you put __w__ back the way it was, one element at a time, that would be unsorting it. Call the resulting array __w'__. Use the exact same transformation on the sorted a to give __a'__. Now __a'__ is what you want. If __a__ was ( 6, 5, 4 ) and w was ( 3, 1, 2), they would , sorted, be (4, 5, 6) and ( 1, 2, 3 ). Now the third in __w__ becomes the first, so the third in the new __a__ becomes the first, the second the second, etc. And you get ( 6, 4, 5 ) in __a'__. It's simpler than it sounds (when I explain it). You just reorder __a__ so it uses __w__'s order.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi: To answer your previous question about both being the same order:  if __w__ is ( 6, 7, 8 ) and __a__ is ( 1, 2, 3 ), Dukeling's answer gives the new __a__ as ( 3, 2, 1 ) where mine gives ( 1, 2, 3 ).  Dukeling gets the very best answer for the first position, second best for the next, and so on.  Mine kind of averages everything out.  And if you want the good answers at the end, you might want to reverse Dukeling's algorithm.

Comment: True. His could be O(n^2) in the worst case, while yours would still be O(n log n). Marked yours as the answer fro being better in the worst case.

Comment: I might add that algorithms like this are exactly why I prefer to keep an array of indices rather than a sorted version of the array itself. Sadly, most programming languages don't have that facility while sorting.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi FYI, my approach is O(n log n) in the worst case.

Comment: @Dukeling If the items of a are already sorted, then the BST formed will have a linear search time, and the overall algorithm will be O(n^2). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi With a simple BST the worst-case running time will be O(n^2), but you can use a [self-balancing BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) (which is what most libraries use) to get a worst-case of O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the example array a:

```
a = {5.5, 6.5, 2.4, 3.1}
```

Now we know that for any number x < 2.75 the closest number in that array will be 2.4 (at index 2). Similarly, for every number x, 2.75 < x < 4.3, the closest number in that array will be 3.1 (at index 3), and so on:

```
upper limit        index
2.75               2
4.3                3
6.0                0
"+infinity"        1
```

Now, using this table finding the closest number in a for w[0] = 1 is easy. Just find the closest upper limit for 1, which is 2.75 and the corresponding index of array a is 2. (This can be optimized by using binary search.)

Since that index can be used only once, we must now alter the table by removing that entry:

```
upper limit        index
4.3                3
6.0                0
"+infinity"        1
```

Next, the closest upper limit for w[1] = 2 is 3 and after removing that the table looks like this:

```
upper limit        index
6.0                0
"+infinity"        1
```

After next step (w[2] = 6) the table has only one entry:

```
upper limit        index
"+infinity"        1
```

In this example we didn't have to remove the last entry from the table during the process. If that needs to be done, then last entry entry of the resulting table has to be updated to have the upper limit of "+infinity".

---

NOTE: I have not checked whether this algorithm actually works!